# Why Autocad map consumes so slow WMS comparing with Arcgis or QGIS, and what can be done about that?

Tags: autocad-map

I created a WMS for aerial photo using Geoserver. Trying to use it with Autocad Map 3d 2013-2014-2015

Why this product consume so bad and slow this and every other WMS?

While the bing aerial used by the same products its very fast. Can be done something about this, or its just the product issue?

Comment: Could you expand upon "consume so bad"? (It's clear what "slow" is.)

Comment: its about rendering, while zooming in and out, it renders very bad, with big squares which gets clearly after 3 seconds. This doesnt happened with other software mentioned above.

Comment: You might look into the cache settings. If it's pulling new data down every time it redraws instead of caching an area locally, it's going to be significantly slower.

Comment: yep, its already activated the option of local cashing, but it doesn't make anything good :(